# Constituent (summary) report: link to contact instead of link to constituent detail?

Tags: civireport

When opening the Constituent (summary) report and clicking on a name in the results list, the page which refers to the specific Constituent detail doesn't open.
Reason for that seems to be the number of activities we have in our database.

Wouldn't it make more sense to change the report, so that, when clicking the name of the contact, it links to the specific contact page instead of linking to the Constituent detail report of that person?

*We are using CMS Drupal and CiviCRM 4.6.33.*

Answer (score 2):

The ["No Drill Down" extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/no-drill-down) will do that for you.

Comment: This is correct - with one caveat.  I'm the author of this extension, and I received a bug report today that it doesn't work on this one particular report template.  I suspect it WILL work on Civi 4.6, but if not, watch out for an update later in the week!

Answer (score 1):

The extension didn't work for me, but I noticed the pattern that it was looking for is different on a WordPress installation. I'm no Civi expert, but I tried rewriting these two lines in nodrilldown.php:

```
/*
$pattern = '/\/civicrm\/report\/instance\/\d*\?reset=1&amp;force=1&amp;id_op=eq&amp;id_value=/';
$replace = '/civicrm/contact/view?reset=1&cid=';
*/
$pattern = '/\=civicrm\/report\/instance\/\d*&amp;reset=1&amp;force=1&amp;id_op=eq&amp;id_value=/';
$replace = '=civicrm/contact/view&reset=1&cid=';
```

It seems to work on WordPress.

Comment: Please open an issue on the Github for the extension? I'll take a look when I have a moment!

Comment: Will do. I'm sure a generalized solution can be implemented much more elegantly!

Comment: I just released a new version of No Drill Down which fixes this issue.